# how to make sure that all service connections are bound?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

I have a Service which needs to be bound because the callers need some feedback and return values. There are at least one Activity, one Fragment and one ContentProvider which should use the bound Service. So alle the using objects call bindService. And all receive onServiceConnected. No problem so far, this works.

But then: The Activity wants all the Fragments to show their content, and they call the ContentProvider. And it happens, that the Fragments and the CP are *not* bound yet. So I can't be sure, that during onServiceConnected all the other Service-using objects are connected.

How to solve this? Some ideas come to my mind:

- Is there a way to control the sequence of the objects receiving the onServiceConnected callback?
- is there a Activity lifecycle callback where I can be sure that all onServiceConnected calls are done? So, is there a better way to start filling the Fragments' content? Or maybe, if I post a message in the Activity's onServiceConnected, can I be sure that this message is processed after all other onServiceConnected-calls?
- Another idea was that I save the bound service connection in a static single field somewhere else. Because the ContentProvider needs access, I thought of the Service class itself. But somehow this seems to go against the idea of a bound service?!?!

Any other ideas?

Thanx, Joerg

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems I found a solution:

in onServiceConnected, I post a message to the UI thread. And to my understanding, this message is processed after all other pending onServiceConnected callbacks are done.

So now my code looks like:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        HeftBinder binder = (HeftBinder)service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                fillAllTheFragments();
            }
        });
    }
```

Does anyone have tried something similar on a dual/quad core device?

Greetings, Joerg

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a pretty simple solution to your problem.

Whenever you bind an Activity, Fragment or ContentProvider to the designated Service, you also tell him who just registered (through a counter of registered elements within the Service).
With a public method within the service, you retrieve the amount of registered elements from your Activity.

```
**Service.java**

private int nb_Fragments = 0;
private int nb_CProviders = 0;    

// Adds an element
public void addBoundElement(String nature)
    nb_Fragments++ OR nb_CProviders++;

// Remove an element
public void unBoundElement(String nature)
    nb_Fragments-- OR nb_CProviders--;

// Are both a Fragment and a ContentProvider bound ?
public boolean areAlreadyBound()
```

You should be able to perform pretty much the same operation implementing a Listener interface in your Service and notifying Activities whenever a new element has been bound or unbound.

Comment: The problem with this solution would be that I don't know what to wait for (how many fragments and CPs). And what to do if they are NOT alreadyBound...